# A device to step down voltage

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power

I’m looking for a device which can take the voltage from a battery and step it down to a lower voltage, for output.

I don’t know the exact name to this device. What would this be called?

Comment: Voltage regulator?

Comment: Can you give us specific values of input and output voltage? intended application?

Voltage regulator is what it is called: there are linear regulator (example LM78xx family regulator entry level to get started, Zener diodes, switching regulator.

Comment: @PeterBennett Yeah I’m trying to find one on Digi-Key. So I gotta be specific. DC voltage regulator?

Comment: @SimonMarcoux Input would be between 9-18V.

Comment: what about the desired output? Current drawn?

Comment: @SimonMarcoux I need this so I can use 9v batteries to power my raspberry Pi through GPIO pins. Pi needs +5V, and a max current of 1 amp. I was thinking of using two 9v batteries for this phase of the prototype, so 18v would be the max input, and since there are no supporting devices, I just need a fixed 5V output.

Comment: @SimonMarcoux Sorry for responding so late, I’ve been really busy.

Comment: A pi requires 5v and 2.5 Amps to run properly. Even better is to provide it with slightly more than 5v (5.15 /5.25 like the most of the recommended wall outlet for Pi). 

increasing the voltage is not what you want, you want to increase your Ah capacity. You need to put your batteries in parallel to do that. Read the answer bellow for possible parts. Keep in mind that at 2.5Amps, one single 9v battery will roughly last 10 minutes and that you might be above the maximum rated current of a single battery.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=15050 Take a look at that...might find it useful

Comment: @SimonMarcoux Yeah I haven’t been able to draft all this out, just a bunch of data I’ve been logging in my brain from research. I figure the batteries should be parallel. I need between at least 30min of runtime. So I need to make more calculations. I needed to see what was on Digi-Key so I could filter my options from there.

Comment: @SimonMarcoux I read a few solid lectures about how to drive power through GPIO’s. At my skill level, I don’t want to mess with the USB port, though the article’s did say what I’m doing still relates to USB power. I’m not an expert on all this, just trying to build something, learning as I go along. One last question though: It is the PI that will regulate current though correct? Because I read in the Pi documentation that the max current the Pi can handle is 1amp; it’s very important that I don’t force more than 1amp through the Pi, cause all documentation has said that will damage the Pi.

Comment: I only played with a raspberry pi 3 so what I will tell you is related to that. Using the GPIO pin to power the raspberry pi is a risky business since you bypass all the built-in protections. My suggestion would be to carry your supply through the usb port so you benefit from the built-in protection of the pi.

While the pi can drain a maximum of 1 amp (hypothesis at this point). ancillary circuits will also draw in current depending on usage and application. For instance, I often uses the raspi screen and I need to take it into account in my current consumption.

Comment: @SimonMarcoux One of the motto's I live by is "Take head to instruction", I will admit that resources have indicated that I should power through USB, but doing that with my skill set seems more monumental than what i was trying to immediately accomplish. Powering through GPIO seemed a lot more "Ghetto" and simpler, though having to factor in the risks. I want to take your advice, but can you tell me how complicated it will be to power through USB? I don't understand USB pins or wiring. What should I read or use as research resources?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76460/discussion-between-iam-pyre-and-simon-marcoux).

Answer (score 2):

A linear voltage regulator will take the voltage down and is very simple to use, but is not very efficient.
(https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-voltage-regulators-linear/699)

You could also use diodes in series to take advantage of their forward voltage drop.

The most efficient but complex solution would be A buck converter also known as a step-down converter. It is known as a switch mode power supply (DC/DC Converter). It can efficiently step down voltages to save battery power.